# Why does synchronous code seem to contradict the definition of the word synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronous

Synchronous is defined as: "existing or occurring at the same time."  Why then is synchronous code blocking?  Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Google Definition: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3A%20synchronous

Comment: Can you share the source? Looks like the reference is out of context.

Comment: A better term might be "sequential", but "a–sequential"?.

Comment: More likely, it's just not a definition that applies to code.  "Synchronous events around the world" is obviously a different usage than "the code ran synchronously".  The code usage means that successive lines of code run one after another.  The first usage means things run at the same time.

Comment: This question would fit better on [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MattJohnson, I would agree with you but this is geared specifically for the programming definition of synchronous and its origin.

Comment: Actually, it would appear that this was asked on StackOverflow before, and then [migrated to english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102150) by a moderator.

Comment: And [here's another dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1596589/634824).  (This one wasn't migrated.)

Answer (score 2):

From Worknik: https://www.wordnik.com/words/synchronous

Although the original definition of the word “synchronous” means:

> *from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition*
>
> *adj.* Occurring or existing at the same time. See Synonyms at contemporary.

In Computer Science it has a totally different definition:

> *from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License*
>
> *adj.* Single-threaded; blocking; occurring in the same thread as other computations, thereby preventing those computations from resuming until the communication is complete.

The reason for this is also explained:

> Lots of times words get perverted, too -- computer scientists who talk of “synchronous processes” have no idea what the actual definition in English of “synchronous” is -- they think it means “synchronized” -- and when they call putting millions of transistors on a tiny chip and call it Very Large Scale Integration, they're turned the phrase “large scale” on its very head.

Essentially, programmers suck at naming things. Hence we have conventions; and [overgeneralizations](http://catb.org/jargon/html/overgeneralization.html).

Comment: "*Essentially, programmers suck at naming things*" yep. Or at least, they subvert the common meaning of things to give them quite different meanings.